# Referencing not working with Natbib

Tags: natbib, apa-style

This is my first LaTeX report and I can't get the referencing to work. I want most of my references to appear as (Author Year) so I'm using `\citet{Crytozine}`. But it appears as *Cryptozine (2)*

```
@Misc{Crytozine,
    Author   = "Cryptozine",
    Title    = "Brief History of Crytography",
    URL      = "http://cryptozine.blogspot.co.uk/2008/05/brief-history-of-cryptography.html",
    note     = "[Accessed: November 2015]",
    year     = 2008,
}
```

I'm using `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` and I have linked the .bib to the LaTeX document.

Comment: Did you load package `apalike` as well?

Comment: The `apalike` bibliography style has been around for more than 20 years. As such, it dates back to a time when `url` fields were pretty much unknown, let alone programmed to be recognized by a BibTeX style file.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `natbib` documentation, when using `apalike`, only parenthetical citations are supported. See p. 24 here: [natbib](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf).

To get parenthetical citations, you should be using \citep{Crytozine} to get the intended (Author Year) behavior.

Comment: Ok, that was a silly mistake lol, now it reads Cryptozine (2)